# Paypal subscription "expires" right away after being added

Tags: paypal, subscriptions

I'm having trouble figuring this out. I would like to create a monthly subscription in paypal that never ends unless the user cancels it. Every time the subscription runs, I want it to call my IPN url.

Below is what I'm using:

```
<script 
    data-env="sandbox" 
    data-callback="" 
    data-period="M" 
    data-recurrence="1" 
    data-currency="USD" 
    data-amount="9.99" 
    data-name="Premium Monthly" 
    data-button="subscribe" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=admin-facilitator@jcink.com"
></script>
```

Note that I removed the IPN url, but anyway, the problem is that no matter how many times I test this, the subscription immediately "expires"

The total cycles listed is "1", the remaining cycles are 0, and the cycle frequency is monthly. What am I getting wrong here? Before anyone says change data-recurrence to 12 for how many months, it doesn't matter, the remaining cycles are always 0. This is really not what I want either; it should be monthly infinitely until the person cancels.

Comment: If it never expires surely you are going to need a considerably larger value for 'remaining cycles 'value than zero?

Answer (score 1):

In order to have it indefinite until the customer cancels you would need to add in data-src="1"